# rails 3 devise before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise for authentication, all it's fine but I want to put the before filter to edit user action which is built in devise and have a problem with it cause it's no controller for it. Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the controller that is used by Devise by specifying it in your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :users => "users" }
```

Then you would create a `UsersController` in your application that inherits from the `Devise::UsersController` and define a `before_filter` at the beginning of this controller:

```
class UsersController < Devise::UsersController
  before_filter :some_filter

  private
    def some_filter
      # some code
    end
end
```

You don't need to define the actions in this controller unless you want to completely override them.